# Sql reverse search for products and discounts

Tags: mysql, sql, string, join, sql-like

I have two table, one for products, and one for discounts.
Discounts table look like:

```
ID | Name         | Percentage | Product Name Search Param
-----------------------------------------------------------
1  | Black Friday | 50         | a
2  | White Friday | 75         | b
```

Product table look like:

```
ID | Name         | Price 
--------------------------
1  | Shoes        | 2500 
2  | Hat          | 1500
3  | Baseball cap | 500
```

If the Product name contain Discount.Product Name Search Param value, then the Product get the Discount percentage. I get the the Products from Discount

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE name LIKE '%a%'
```

But i don't have any idea how to get one Product Discounts.

I want to get the Product with `ID` `2` which discount is due.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join with a `like` condition:

```
select p.*, d.*
from product p
inner join discounts d 
    on p.name like concat('%', d.product_name_seach_param, '%')
```

Note: as far as concerns, your design does not look good. It would be better to have a referential tables for products and one for discounts, and a *junction table* that relates products to discounts.

Answer (score 1):

A simple INNER JOIN should do it:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Products
JOIN Discounts ON Products.name LIKE CONCAT('%', product_name_search_param`, '%')
```